# How to read the gsm modem messages in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modem, cellid

I need the the cell-id information to display in my iphone app, the app sends AT commands to the modem but...I do not know how to read the modem messages. Please help me.

Comment: Added the iphone tag, unsure about the cellid tag as there is only one other question tagged with it.

Comment: What I am try to do is the following:
int speed = 115200;
 unsigned int null = 0;
 unsigned int handshake = TIOCM_DTR | TIOCM_RTS | TIOCM_CTS| TIOCM_DSR;
 struct termios term;
 int fd = open("/dev/tty.debug", O_RDWR | 0x20000 | O_NOCTTY);
write(fd,"AT+COPS?\r\n",strlen("AT+COPS?\r\n"));
//Read the response from the modem.
 I need the LAC,MCC,MNC to calculate the position. thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are asking in context of the iPhone, then I don't think you are allowed to do that with the official SDK.

You should look at the source code of the unlock tools by the team because they send AT commands to read data from the iphone modem.

Comment: This is most definitely not permitted in the official SDK. If you try to submit this to the App Store, it will get rejected, certainly.

Comment: There is another way to get the cellid?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of functionality you need, but [this website](http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp) took me quiet far in sending text messages with the AT command set.

Furthermore you can use the windows hyperterminal (Accessories>Communication) to connect to the specific USB port (mapped on a COM port). With this connection you can send AT commands yourself to the cell phone and see what it returns.

Hope this helps...